# How do I wrap the pre-filter around the HEPA filter in this air purifier?

Tags: installation, air-filter, filter

I bought [this air purifier](http://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00007E7RY/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) and was installing the pre-filter that came with it. The instructions go "Carefully wrap the pre-filter around the HEPA filter so that the ends meet. Fasten the ends together with the fastener provided."

The pre-filter is longer than the HEPA is wide so does this mean
1)Wrap the pre-filter around the HEPA so the pre-filter's ends are touching and the pre-filter sits loosly over the HEPA
**or**
2)Wrap the pre-filter snugly around the HEPA so that the pre-filter's ends overlap

Here is pictures of how I have it now with slightly overlapping ends
[image: side view of air filter]
[image: top view of air filter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ends overlap

[image]

Image Source [Amazon](http://www.amazon.ca/Honeywell-38002-Activated-Carbon-Prefilter/dp/B000050H5N/ref=pd_sim_sbs_k_1/175-9035629-8256047)